# NullPointerException when triggering Java method from C++ via JNI

Tags: android, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x

I could call a non-static java method via JNI like below:

[C++ code]

```
jclass classID = minfo.env->FindClass("com/halfmeters/sangosloto/AliPayActivity");
jmethodID method = minfo.env->GetMethodID(classID,"pay","(Ljava/lang/String;)Z");
jobject obj = minfo.env->NewObject(classID, method);
jstring strOrder = minfo.env->NewStringUTF("test");
jboolean result = minfo.env->CallBooleanMethod(obj, method,strOrder);//minfo.methodID);
minfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(strOrder);
minfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(minfo.classID);
```

[java method declaration]

```
public boolean pay(String orderInfo){
    System.out.println("Order info:" + orderInfo); // caught an exception
}
```

now when executed the function in C++, it throws an exception by java side like below:

```
09-06 11:46:45.229: E/AndroidRuntime(31141): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 12
09-06 11:46:45.229: E/AndroidRuntime(31141): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-06 11:46:45.229: E/AndroidRuntime(31141): at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:347)
09-06 11:46:45.229: E/AndroidRuntime(31141): at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:155)
09-06 11:46:45.229: E/AndroidRuntime(31141): at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:217)
09-06 11:46:45.229: E/AndroidRuntime(31141): at com.test.AliPayActivity.pay(AliPayActivity.java:322)
09-06 11:46:45.229: E/AndroidRuntime(31141): at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.nativeTouchesEnd(Native Method)
09-06 11:46:45.229: E/AndroidRuntime(31141): at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.handleActionUp(Cocos2dxRenderer.java:79)
09-06 11:46:45.229: E/AndroidRuntime(31141): at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView$10.run(Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView.java:345)
09-06 11:46:45.229: E/AndroidRuntime(31141): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1326)
09-06 11:46:45.229: E/AndroidRuntime(31141): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1118)
```

could anyone help to check what's wrong with it? thanks!
P.S. I found the java method pay(String) is called twice in this procedure, but I don't know how it comes.

Comment: I think the orderInfo is not been passed to Java correctly

Comment: I just don't know how to find the problem. in fact i have a null value validation in java method, which is not triggered when being called.

Comment: What happens when you try to copy orderInfo (`orderInfo = new String(orderInfo)`)?

Comment: Did you find the problem ? I have similar problem here : 1) similar crash 2) method called twice !  That's crazy... Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try logging with

```
Log.d("", "Order info:" + orderInfo);
```

It seems like the system call can't work if this method is called from the native side.

Comment: thx for your reply, but it still doesn't work after I changed the code. Indeed, I have another log like:  System.out.println("starting pay");   , which could be printed in console(LogCat):